# Download file from XMLPullParser

Tags: java, xml-parsing, onclick, zip, android-xmlpullparser

I am quite new developer.
I am building an app with AndroidStudio that read an XML file from server with PullParser. I need to download a file.zip from xml link and when I press the buttonDownload(inside the raw Layout of listView) it should start to download file. 
Here is the code of my row layout of my SitesAdapter.

```
public View getView(final int pos, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent){
    RelativeLayout row = (RelativeLayout)convertView;
    Log.i("AtlantisSites", "getView pos = " + pos);
    //ViewHolder mainViewHolder = null;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if(null == row){
//No recycled View, we have to inflate one.
        LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_site, null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.btnDownload = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btnDownload);
        viewHolder.btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Integer pos=(Integer)v.getTag();
                Log.i("AtlantisSites", "getView pos = " + pos);
                String url = getItem(pos).getLink();
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            }
        });
row.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
viewHolder.btnDetails.setTag(getItem(pos));

public class ViewHolder{
    Button btnDownload;
    Button btnDetails;
}
```

and here is the class where I should call the getLink() to start the download file.zip

```
public class DownloadZip {



public void DownloadFromUrlZip(){
    try {


        URL url = new URL (s);

        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setDoOutput(true);
        c.connect();

        String Path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
        Log.v("AtlantisSites", "PATH: " + Path);
        File file = new File(Path);
        file.mkdirs();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("AtlantisIssue.zip");

        InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len1 = 0;
        while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
        }
        fos.close();
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("AtlantisSites", "Error: " + e);
    }
    Log.v("AtlantisSites", "Check: ");

}
```

After the download I have to unzip file and save it in the internal storage.
the point is that I don't know how to call the getLink() to start downloading from it.
I tried so many times and ways.
I am stuck on it.

Please, any helps will be really apreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), DownloadZip.class);
 v.getContext().startActivity(i);
```

I wrote this inside my button in the ViewHolder. and create a method Download.class